# emacs hangs when loading csharp (.cs) file

Tags: init-file, csharp-mode

Just upgraded to emacs 26.1 from 25.3 on windows (emacs-version = GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30). 
I downloaded the latest version of csharp-mode from melpa.

Now when I'm trying to load a (any) csharp file emacs will hang and I have to kill it using process explorer / task manager. I never had this issue with the old emacs version.

My question: Does anybody has the same issue with this combination and is there a possible solution?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling csharp-mode *after* the upgrade?

Comment: Yes. I removed the old version first and installed the new one. I was checking for references to old paths as well.

Answer (score 1):

After some trying out I found out that I have other packages which are not working properly. They showed the same behaviour, e.g. Speedbar brought EMACS to a grinding halt.
After looking at my customization I found out that I had some character replacement to use with Fira Code. After removing of this replacement everything works fine.